# Making replicas

Tags: cutting

I am an arm-chair DIY. I want to make about 75 pieces of this component using OSB. The pieces of do not have to be perfect or smooth.

[image]

I have used a jigsaw and an oscillating multi-tool to cut few pieces, but it is taking a long time. Any suggestions on how to create replicas of this component?

Comment: You show a width of 3/4" and the piece looks substantially thinner than it is wide.  Is this 1/4" thick OSB?  Personally, I would probably construct these out of individual pieces and join them together instead of trying to cut this out of a sheet whole.  Each component can be batched out pretty easily with stop blocks on a miter saw.

Comment: Another option is to stack  6 or 8 panels and tape them together to run through a bandsaw (if you've got access to one). What power tools do you have?

Comment: This is 1/2” thick OSB. Like your ideas. How do you suggest I join them? This supposed to stand upright.

Comment: 75 pieces, ouch. I can't think of any way of really speeding up the process working manually, other than batch-processing some of the key cuts.

Comment: Do you have good plunge-cutting-with-a-circular-saw skills? I'd stack 5 sheets, plunge as many of the straight lines as possible, then finish with a jigsaw.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly the only fast way is going to be with a CNC router.

Failing that you might be able to make yourself a template and then use a handheld router with a bearing-guided pattern bit - you do then need to worry about how you will attach the template to the workpieces. You could clamp them down but then the clamps will get in the way. You'd also need to clear out any internal corners with further sawing, chiselling etc. (since a router will leave a rounded internal corner).

There's a video on using a template with a follower bit here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hw4uAVNvk58&ab_channel=eHow

As per Graphus's comment below, if using a router bit on OSB you will need to consider tool wear. I'm not sure of the tool-wearing characteristics of OSB specifically but I know that other particle boards can cause very high tool wear. A tungsten-carbide bit might help, or it may be more economical to use "cheapy" bits but get a few of them and/or resharpen every so often. Depending on what the parts will be used for and how good the edge finish needs to be, you may want to get a spiral cutter or even a "compression" cutter to help with edge-chipping. See here for router bit recommendations: [When should I use a spiral router bit?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/833/when-should-i-use-a-spiral-router-bit/835)

Comment: Cutting using a router with template bushing and straight cutting bit sounds appealing. Will check it out.

Comment: @MAmarasinghe This may be the best way by far for you to do this. But note that the density of OSB may put a strain on your router's motor. Also, the hardness of the material (add to that any contaminants) will make it very wearing so you may go through more than one bit doing the cuts.

Comment: Good point @Graphus, I have edited the answer to include some more info on this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're stacking a pile of these to add your third dimension.

### Make a sandwich of straight strips.

You can accomplish by breaking your shape up into two versions made of straight, ¾" strips. Take the following simple example. By stacking Alpha-Beta-Alpha-… the corner is well-reinforced. Perhaps not *as* strong, but strong enough. Quantity is key and you have that by the bucket.

I've no idea what this technique is called. Answers on a postcard.

> [image]

Build yourself a cut list for both versions, turn a load of sheets into ¾" stock and take it to the mitre saw. You're going to save yourself a *ton* of OSB this way but more than anything you're going to save time. You're going to be able to set a stop block and cut up to copies one after another.

You're going to save so much wood, you might be able to upgrade to a nice ply.

Glue up becomes interesting. Build yourself a template, or a negative and that can help you align things. Don't be afraid to do this in multiple steps. Normally I would say you could assemble each stacked part first and then assemble the shape but the quantity and the material would make this too tedious to try and bring together.

Comment: Even for non-stacking, making a simple lap joint (i.e. removing half the material from each mating part) can be fairly easy with a dado-stack, router table or multiple passes with a regular table saw blade. This will give you a flat joint for the pieces.